# Remove all inner HTML except text using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, image

I have the following HTML Code -

```
<label id="label_id" >
   What is your name? 
   <img src=/info_icon.gif" id="tooltip">
   <div id="tooltip_modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <span id="tooltip_close">&times;</span>
            <h5>Information</h5>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p> Some Sample text
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</label>
```

Using JavaScript I fetched the `<label>` element like this -

```
var myLabel = document.getElementById("label_id");
```

I want to get rid of everything inside the `<label>` element except `What is your name?`

Please note that "What is your name?" represents a piece of text that will be generated dynamically and inserted into the `<label>` element.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Do you want it to just keep the first line (whatever it is) inside the label tags, or everything that's not a tag, up to the first tag (and delete thes rest)?

Comment: good way to control is just wrap `What is your name?` with `<span>` => `<span id="text">What is your name?</span>`. so you can keep text inside and put it back after clean html inside label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the first text node which would be 'What is your name?' and replace the content of the `label` by it - see demo below:

```js
var myLabel = document.getElementById("label_id");
// get the first text node
var textNode = myLabel.childNodes[0];
// replace the content of label by the text
myLabel.textContent = textNode.textContent;
```

```html
<label id="label_id" >
   What is your name? 
   <img src="/info_icon.gif" id="tooltip"/>
   <div id="tooltip_modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <span id="tooltip_close">&times;</span>
            <h5>Information</h5>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p> Some Sample text
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

> myLabel.innerHtml = 'What is your name?';

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myLabel = document.getElementById("label_id");
myLabel.innerHTML = 'What is your name?';
```

```html
<label id="label_id" >
   What is your name? 
   <img src="/info_icon.gif" id="tooltip"/>
   <div id="tooltip_modal">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <span id="tooltip_close">&times;</span>
            <h5>Information</h5>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <p> Some Sample text
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</label>
```